# Merge sort implementation with various improvements

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

So I was working on merge sort today, and was trying to speed it up. I would like your opinion on the implementation and if it's possible to make it faster. Besides that I was wondering if there are any mistakes that i am making code wise, things that are considered a bad practice.

I like making algorithms for fun, and then when i make them I always try to improve them. One thing that I have noticed which i couldn't wrap my head around was that when you give a reverse sorted array as input it works faster than when you don't.

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] array) {
    mergeDivider(array,0,array.length-1);
}

private static void mergeDivider(int[] array, int lowBound, int highBound) {
    if(lowBound < highBound) {
        int middle = (lowBound + highBound)/2;

        if((highBound - lowBound) <= 43){
            //Found online that insertion sort is faster for n <= 43
            mergeSortInsertionSortSpeedUp(array,lowBound,highBound);
        } else {
            //Normal divide and conquer
            mergeDivider(array, lowBound, middle);
            mergeDivider(array, middle + 1, highBound);

            if(array[middle] > array[middle + 1]){
                mergeSortMerger(array, lowBound, middle, highBound);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Merge method
private static void mergeSortMerger(int[] array, int lowBound, int middle, int highBound) {
    //Doesn't make seperate copies for left and right only makes a temporary array
    int left_index = lowBound, right_index = middle + 1,temp_index = 0;
    int[] temp_holder = new int[highBound - lowBound + 1];

    while(left_index <= middle && right_index <= highBound){
        if(array[left_index] < array[right_index]){
            temp_holder[temp_index++] = array[left_index++];
        } else {
            temp_holder[temp_index++] = array[right_index++];
        }
    }

    while(left_index <= middle){
        temp_holder[temp_index++] = array[left_index++];
    }
    while(right_index <= highBound){
        temp_holder[temp_index++] = array[right_index++];
    }

    //Put everything in the original array
    for(int x = lowBound, k = 0; x <=highBound;x++,k++){
        array[x] = temp_holder[k];
    }
}

private static void mergeSortInsertionSortSpeedUp(int[] array, int left, int right){
    for(int x = left; x <= right;x++){
        int temp = array[x];
        int before = x - 1;
        while(before >= left && array[before] > temp){
            array[before+1] = array[before];
            before--;
        }
        array[before+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `was trying to speed [up merge-sort]` Advice: be explicit about the base-line, think about/design a benchmark, look around if there's something useful (framework, test-set(-generator), whole benchmark). If possible, set a performance goal. For tape sort, there used to be multi-way merge-sorts: care to argue relevance thereof?

Comment: (*faster with reverse sorted input* is most probably due to branch prediction.)

Answer (score 1):

- Mandatory stability note: the sequence

  ```
      if(array[left_index] < array[right_index]){
          temp_holder[temp_index++] = array[left_index++];
      } else {
          temp_holder[temp_index++] = array[right_index++];
      }
  ```

  causes loss of stability (equal elements are merged in the wrong order).
- The code still does unnecessary copying (from `tmp` back to `array`). It is unnecessary because it can be avoided. Allocate a temporary array once, then

  ```
      merge_sort subrange 0 of arr into corresponding subrange of tmp
      merge_sort subrange 1 of arr into corresponding subrange of tmp
      merge subranges from tmp to arr
  ```
- The insertion sort implementation is suboptimal. Testing two conditions in

  ```
      while(before >= left && array[before] > temp)
  ```

  can be avoided. Take a look at the Alex Stepanov's [technique](https://github.com/psoberoi/stepanov-conversations-course/blob/master/languages/java/Quicksort64.java) (he is talking about quicksort, but the first 4 methods, which you are are only interested in, are equally applicable to your case).
- The algorithms of this kind generally look better at the semi-open ranges. Try to rewrite the code with the assumption that `highBound` *does not* belong to the range.

Comment: Thank you for you response, I was wondering what you meant with your second point. I vaguely understand what you mean, but not completely. I get that I might be able to do it more efficiently, but everytime i have tried so far, it didn't really do anything.